# JS changing variabile onmouseover

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I try to change a variable onmouseover, this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x;
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        console.log (x);
    });        
});
</script>
<div class="button" onmouseover="x = 'y'"> Button </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `x` variables.

- The *global* `x` that is implicitly created when you assign `'y'` to it
- The `x` in the scope of the anonymous function you pass to `ready()` which is explicitly created by `var x;`.

You are giving a value to one and logging the value of the other.

---

Don't use intrinsic event attributes. Just bind your event handlers through JavaScript. Then you can keep your scope clear and make sure you are only dealing with a single `x`.

```js
$(function() {
  var x;
  $("button").on('mouseover', setValue);
  $("button").on('mouseover', logValue);

  function setValue() {
    x = "y";
  }

  function logValue() {
    console.log(x);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

---

NB: HTML has a perfectly good button element. You don't need to use a class to represent that.

Comment: Thank you it`s working, I just do not have to declare the x variabile in the function